# No print to stdout when running xmlrunner in python

Tags: python, linux, unit-testing

I'm using `xmlrunner` in combination with `unittest` in python for testing purposes by running

`xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(outsuffix="",).run(suite)`

where suite is standard `unittest.suite.TestSuite`

When I run the tests on my windows machine I get an output by using the standard `print()` function in my tests. Unfortunately I don't get any output to my terminal when running the tests on my fedora machine. The output is correctly logged to an XML file but I would like to have the output directly to stdout / terminal.

Did I miss something that explains this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the reason. On my Fedora 24 machine an old version of xmlrunner (1.14.0 - something) was installed. I used pip to install the lates xmlrunner (1.7.7) for python3 and now I do get the output directly on the terminal.